# Getting list functions in file that imported a module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

This is for a project I am working on to help my own workflow, and nothing that is for production. So I understand that what I am doing is probably definitely not the right thing to do, but I am curious if it is possible anyways.

I have some code like this:

#### A.py:

```
from B import *

def f1():
    ...

def f2():
    ...

...
```

Is there any way for module `B`, when imported, to get a list of the functions defined in the importer, `A.py`?

I thought about using the inspect module, to inspect the call stack. But I was unsure where the entry point would be, I assume it would be in the global scope of `B.py`. I am also unsure what the call stack looks like when importing a module.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `A` hasn't finished executing when `from B import *` is encountered so the best you could probably do is manual parsing of `A` in `B` and then trying to find function defs. That still won't guarantee that they are actually defined, for all you know there might be `del` statements there, dynamically created functions and god knows what else.

Comment: Even though `A` hasn't finished executing, if `B` could find the path of the file that imported it, it can import that file and then get the function definitions. How could `B` find the path of the file that imported it?

Comment: Importing that module will get the existing reference to the incomplete module.

Comment: I see... Well, I wasn't super confident that what I was trying to do was possible. So, how would I go about finding what file imported `B`? If I can do that, that would already help immensely.

Comment: I don't think you'd even get an incomplete reference, pretty sure Python will detect the circular import and stop you in your tracks.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard: Python doesn't care what you import; it won't stop you unless you do something that would cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what module you are going to import **B.py** in then you could have something like this:

**A.py**

```
import B

def f1():
    return 1

def f2():
    return 1

def f3():
    return 1

if __name__=="__main__":
    print temp.allF()
```

**B.py**

```
import inspect, A

def allF():
    return inspect.getmembers(A, inspect.isfunction)
```

When you run **A.py** it will give you a list of functions.
I'm not sure if there is a way to access the script which imports a given module, but if this is possible then you could change **B.py** slightly to use this.

Comment: The issue is I don't know the name of the module that is importing `B.py`. :/ I have resorted to loading the functions from the main module using inspect, for now anyways.