# Get path of importing module

Tags: python, import, python-import

I have two python files: main.py and imported.py.  I want to import imported.py into main.py but I want access to the path of main.py in the file imported.py.  That is I want access to the path of the importing module.  For example:

```
#main.py
import imp
imported = imp.load_source('imported', "/absolute/path/to/imported.py")

#imported.py
pathToImportingModule=os.path.??? 
doSomethingWithPath(pathToImportingModule)
```

Comment: This question seems to be similar, with no answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081310/getting-list-functions-in-file-that-imported-a-module

Comment: This looks like an X-Y problem. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: imported.py is a general script that I will run a lot.  This script will do tasks related to the folder that main.py is in.  For example, it will create a new folder in the same folder that main.py is in, and create files in that folder.  I know I can simply get the path of folder that conatins main.py in main.py using os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath(__file__))) and then pass that to imported.py, but I wondering if there is a way to do this automatically.

Comment: @user1763510. How about: `os.path.abspath(sys.modules['__main__'].__file__)`?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for ekhumoro

Comment: @user1763510 I'm glad you found your solution. I hope you don't mind if I offer an alternative: put main.py together with imported.py, don't use `imp.load_source`, don't do things *"in the same folder that main.py is in"*, do things in current working directory instead, or take the work directory as an argument. That way you will have a much more logical setup which will be easier to maintain.

Comment: @zvone I agree that this isn't the most logical and clean setup.  However, I am trying to share this imported.py file with other individuals that will create the main.py file on their own.  These other users may not be so competent with python so I want to make this as simple and minimal as possible to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution received in comments from ekhumoro:

```
#main.py
import imp
imported = imp.load_source('imported', "/absolute/path/to/imported.py")


#imported.py
pathToImportingModule=os.path.abspath(sys.modules['__main__'].__file__)    
doSomethingWithPath(pathToImportingModule)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any "importing" notification hook.
You can achieve some what similar thing by explicitly calling a function into imported module:

```
#main.py
import imp
import sys
import os

imported = imp.load_source('imported', "/absolute/path/to/imported.py")
imported.doSomething(os.path.abspath(sys.modules[__name__].__file__))

#imported.py
def doSomething(importing_path):
   print ("Importing path: ", importing_path)
   pass
```